# How to grab the attribute value using beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(f.read())
data=soup.findAll('node',{'id':'memory'})
print data
```

Output

```
[<node id="memory" claimed="true" class="memory" handle="DMI:000E">
<description>
  System Memory
 </description>
<physid>
  e
 </physid>
<slot>
  System board or motherboard
 </slot>
<size units="bytes">
  3221225472
 </size>
<capacity units="bytes">
  3221225472
 </capacity>
</node>]
```

Now how will I grab the attributes value like the data between tag  that is System Memory and so on. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get `<...>this</...>` you should use [contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents) field, so in your case it would be:

```
print data.description.contents
```

To get [attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Changing%20attribute%20values) access them as they were a dictionary

```
print data.size['units']
```

And to iterate all the tags, use [findAll](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) that you already know:

```
for node in data.findAll(True):
  # do stuff on node
```

Answer (score 1):

beautifulsoup can create a tree. you can then iterate over that tree and get the attributes

check out the following link
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#TheattributesofTags